# Jira Tampermonkey Script to write work description in Log Work

Tags: javascript, html, jira, tampermonkey

I'm currently trying to write a Tampermonkey Script that automatically fills in default Text in the Textarea "Work Description" ([As seen in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH8KX.png)). The code in Jira is

```
<textarea class="textarea long-field long-field" cols="60" id="comment" name="comment" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Normally (and as testet in other instances), when getting the element with `document.getElementById("comment")`, one can say `.value` and get the content of the text area. In all other text fields, this works, and normally, textareas work too, as shown below

```js
function printa() {
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a").value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="printa()">Show content of textarea</button>
<p id="b"></p>
```

Removing everything but the ID doesn't affect the outcome.

This just doesn't work in my case. I don't know, what Jira does there, but somehow, it doesn't work.

Note: All this was tested both in Console and in a Tampermonkey Script, but neither work, and I think, including the tampermonkey script before having a solution for the console is useless.

Note 2: I tested it in Chromium and Firefox, resulting in the same behaviour

Edit: Jira is being stupid, there are multiple elements with `id="comment"`. And ofc, JS selects the one I don't want. So now it's about finding a specific textarea, while both have the ID comment

Comment: I know your pain. I have a Jira userscript that converts "rest" into remaining amount of hours to be logged for the day. I need to press another button to get jira to consume the new value. I might take a look if I can fix that and let you know.

Comment: But basically the gist is you need to dispatch some events to get Jira to acknowledge the value.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica As I found (and it says in the Edit), sadly not, that would have been easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now that I found the problem, the fix was fairly easy, if atrocious.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#comment")[1].value
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this also. With React and Angular type apps, multiple IDs on the page is becoming not so rare.

The solution that always works for me is to be more specific in my (CSS-ish) selectors. So, instead of selecting:

```
$('#comment').val()
```

I will use a much more detailed selector:

```
$('body > div:nth-child(3) .nuther-area > div:nth-child(2) #comment').val()
```

Surprisingly, this allows you to access the correct ID tag... although by using the above methods one can just select the element itself without using its ID tag.

Only problem, of course, is that from time to time your selectors will need to be adjusted as the page structure changes. In my experience, though, that tends to happen rarely.

*(Apologies for using jQuery in my example - I write it faster. The point is not to give you code, but to demonstrate a technique, which will be the same in pure js)*

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, because the structure does not allow it. It's pretty much the same thing twice, with a few classes more at the wrong one. But I know, what you mean, the answer I posted just is a bit easier and shorter for me